# Methods are being called yet not executing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

So my Twitter/Facebook implementation in my app has been a learning experience, but I'm almost there and I have one last, probably simple question. Using the MGTwitter engine, I'm calling a method from my viewcontroller in

```
 - (void) setAccessToken: (OAServiceTicket *) ticket withData: (NSData *) data {
```

The method is firing off, (confirmed by NSLog calls). However, it's not doing what it's supposed to do, which is fade in my logout button for Twitter. I'm still getting my hands around the way Objective-C handles methods and all, I feel like I'm just not pointing my variables to the right place. Any direction is much appreciated, here is the code below:

SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m -

```
//
// access token callback
// when twitter sends us an access token this callback will fire
// we store it in our ivar as well as writing it to the keychain
// 
- (void) setAccessToken: (OAServiceTicket *) ticket withData: (NSData *) data {
    if (!ticket.didSucceed || !data) return;

    NSString *dataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    if (!dataString) return;

    if (self.pin.length && [dataString rangeOfString: @"oauth_verifier"].location == NSNotFound) dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingFormat: @"&oauth_verifier=%@", self.pin];

    NSString                *username = [self extractUsernameFromHTTPBody:dataString];

    if (username.length > 0) {
        [self setUsername: username password: nil];
        if ([_delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(storeCachedTwitterOAuthData:forUsername:)]) [(id) _delegate storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: dataString forUsername: username];
    }

    [_accessToken release];
    _accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:dataString];
    //Call twit login from my view controller
    MyView *fvController = [[MyView alloc] init];
    [MyView twitLogin];
    [MyView helper];
    NSLog(@"LETS TWEET DIRECTLY AFTER SUCCESSFUL LOG IN!");

}
```

This is what my helper method is doing in my .m file:

```
-(void)helper{
    NSLog(@"HELPER FUNCTION");
    [self fadeIn:twitterLogout withDuration:2 andWait:2.0];
}
```

This is the method it's calling

```
//FADE IN FUNCTION ------------------------------//////////////////////

-(void)fadeIn:(UIView*)viewToFadeIn withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
      andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade In" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    viewToFadeIn.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, methods are declared in one of two ways:

```
- (returnType)methodName;
```

or

```
+ (returnType) methodName;
```

The first type is an "instance" method and the second type is a "class" method.

These lines should be changed:

```
[MyView twitLogin];
[MyView helper];
```

Try this instead:

```
[fvController twitLogin];
[fvController helper];
```

Additionally, you may be calling your helper method before the delegate returns a value. You should see if the MGTwitterEngine contains a delegate. (I'd be surprised if it didn't.) You should use the available callbacks to call methods only when the login is finished. Simply calling the methods in order won't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help the other day, yes I corrected my method calls, and after digging deep into the API and searching more tutorials, I found out how to call MGTwitter's Login Success delegate and everything is working perfectly. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*Are both the log statements printed?

*Is setAccessToken:withData: being called from the main thread? Try calling the fadeIn method from the main thread i.e. something like this

```
- (void) helper{
    NSLog(@"HELPER FUNCTION");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callFadeIn)];
}    
-(void)callFadeIn{
    [self fadeIn:twitterLogout withDuration:2 andWait:2.0];
}
```

See if that helps. It is possible that setAccessToken: (and thus helper and fadeIn) is being called from another thread. All UI operations should happen from the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this corrected some other warnings I was receiving, I appreciate your time :)